# Select value of one column from another table and provide other values explicitly

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin, insert-into

I have 2 tables:

```
cities(city_id|Serial, city_name|Text, state_id|Integer)
states(state_id|Serial, state_name|Text)
```

I want to insert a row in `cities` having `city_name` as "PortBlair", and the corresponding `state_id` to be taken from `states` where `state_name="Andaman"`.

**My query**:

```
INSERT INTO cities (city_name,state_id) 
VALUES ('PortBlair',select state_id from states where state_name='Andaman')
```

**Error in MySQL**:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select state_id from states where state_name='Andaman')' at line 1
```

**Question1**: What is wrong with this statement? Am I missing some qoutes/backquotes/apostrophes?

**Question2**: Should I rely on `Serial` datatype in the sense that it will always generate the same Id if the order of insert statements is the same? I mean, should I just write the `state_id` myself as:

```
INSERT INTO cities (city_name,state_id) VALUES ('PortBlair',1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to enclose the select statement with parenthesis as your are getting value,

```
INSERT INTO cities (city_name,state_id) 
VALUES ('PortBlair', (select state_id from states where state_name='Andaman'))
```

but better use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` Statement

```
INSERT INTO cities (city_name,state_id) 
SELECT 'PortBlair' as city_name, state_id
FROM states 
WHERE state_name = 'Andaman'
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1:

```
INSERT INTO cities (city_name,state_id) 
select 'PortBlair' as city, state_id 
from states where state_name='Andaman'
```

Q2:

Yes, you can write state_id your self:

```
INSERT INTO cities (city_name,state_id) VALUES ('PortBlair',1)
```